# Strategies for using Turian Solider proximity mines

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

I've been playing around with the Turian Solider class in multiplayer, and haven't had much luck using the proximity mines.  All I ever get out of them are some minor assists in the end.

What are the best skill selections to take to maximize their effectiveness, and what are some good ways to use them?

Comment: In my experience attempting to get any use out of Garrus's Prox Mine, the answer is that the skill selection which maximizes effectiveness of Prox Mine is no points in Prox Mine. YMMV.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz humans are able to use prox mines with much better effectiveness than the silly NPC AI

Comment: @yx. I meant manually controlling his casting, not AI use.

Comment: Its still a huge difference from having to bring up the squad menu every 5 seconds to spam a mine rather than just aiming at a spot and hitting a single key.  I totally ignored mines in single player as well.  Also, in single player you are constantly moving to a new area as in multiplayer you're defending a zone most of the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I use the proximity mine on my Turian soldier is to supplement his primary damage source: weapons, rather than relying it as a damage dealer.  For my soldier, I only max out proximity mine after the following skills:

- Marksman
- Turian Veteran
- Fitness

Its arguable that you can start putting more points into mines rather than fitness, but I prefer the survivability first.

Here are the key upgrades for the mines that I like to use:

- Rank 4: Radius
- Rank 5: Damage Taken
- Rank 6: Recharge Speed

My weapons:

- Falcon assault rifle (clip size and scope mod)
- backup SMG of some kind (damage and clip mod)

Key points:

- The AOE effect of the mine that boost damage done to enemies synergizes really well with the AOE damage of the falcon assault rifle.
- Proximity mines last forever (as long as you don't place them too close to each other), so be constantly spamming them, even in between rounds.
- Your weapons are your primary source of damage, though granted I've never tried a skill spamming soldier before.
- Since the Turian soldier doesn't have a dodge mechanism, you'll need the extra health and good positioning to survive.
- If you can see the location with your scope, you can place a mine there, even if its far away.  Spam your mines everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I use it to stagger large enemies like the Geth Prime and the Cerberus Guardian, which allows me to get crucial sniper or AR shots. They're also an early warning system when I'm sniping on a useless team.

Answer (score 0):

You realy want to take Damage Taken with infiltrator and a strong sniper weapon like Widow. You just go to cloak, fire the mine, then you snipe him. Try it - you will eat prime for breakfast, not just prime everything